# Why car has sharp separation edges at the back?

Tags: flow, drag, aerodynamics, turbulence

Most new cars that gain low drag have sharp separation edges at the back.

If edges are round than wake is smaller but curvature produce low pressure, if edges are sharp wake is larger but dont have low pressure.

So what solution is better and why?

You can see at rear bumper one sharp line that will stop air to follow curvature of bumper.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a car you want a controlled separation. The sharp edge produces a shallow pressure profile up to the edge, at which the flow separates cleanly. If the contour were round, separation would happen somewhere along the contour and will be asymmetrical between left and right sides in a crosswind. With the high pressures at high speed, such asymmetrical pressure has the potential to produce unwanted side forces which negatively affect handling.

Comment: In straight line without wind, has car with sharp edges lower drag then with round edges?

Comment: @LostincurvedSpace-Time it depends. Not always. It is less about drag than control at high speed.

Comment: I noticed that all ultra low drag cars has sharp edges ,like mercedes IAA, Volkswagen XL1 etc so I thought this is because of drag reduction..Does has any study/pdf about that specific topic?

Comment: @LostincurvedSpace-Time All ultra-low drag cars also have issues with aero forces at high speed. Generally, the topic was pioneered by [Wunibald Kamm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wunibald_Kamm). Google for [Kammback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kammback) to learn more. Initially the idea was to reduce drag while maintaining a practical shape, but stability soon became more important as cars became much faster, involving much higher aero forces.