# Has car round back any aero advantages?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, drag, aerodynamics, turbulence

All Porsches have round back so much(top to down and also side to back) that people know  to joke that car has lower drag when drive in reverse!

Does so much round back has any aerodynamics advantages compare to cut off back?

round  back
[image]

cut-off,sharp back
[image]

[image]

Comment: What you call a roundback just looks like a smaller cutoff back to me.

Comment: Both look like rounded backs to me. Perhaps change the image?

Comment: The aerodynamics of cars like these are generally very specific to the vehicle.  There are also brand design requirements.  This is at best engineering and even marketing.  I don't think it's on-topic here.

Comment: @StephenG I am not interested in brand styling,I interested in deep aerodynamics...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why car has sharp separation edges at the back?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/668653/why-car-has-sharp-separation-edges-at-the-back)

Comment: @PeterKämpf No,here is answer why sharp edges are use for, but still dont see any aero adventages of round edges.From your answer round edges dont have any adventages,only drawbacks.

Comment: So you keep asking this question until you get the answer you desire? Sorry, this site doesn't work like that. Here we give evidence-based answers, and this evidence doesn't change just because some random person doesn't like it.

Comment: @PeterKampf Where did you mention any advantages of round edges?I just say that you didnt write any advantages od round edge.. I agree with all what  you wrote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [pointed](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/89367/does-c-d-change-with-speed/89381#89381) out [before](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/668653/why-car-has-sharp-separation-edges-at-the-back/668843?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C88.6449#668843), this is less about drag than control.

A sloped back delays separation, making the separated area smaller. At the same time, it adds wetted surface, adding friction drag. At some point it is better to cut off the car body in order to minimize overall drag. This is called a [Kammback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kammback), after [Wunibald Kamm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wunibald_Kamm).

The low drag of a Kammback makes the car fast. Aerodynamic forces grow with speed squared, so at high speed they become dominant and will influence handling. Now it is important to have sharp edges at the back in order to avoid suction peaks. Especially in crosswinds, the forces added by the suction areas can make the car uncontrollable at high speed. This is similar to avoiding round boat bottoms at high speed.

Rounding the back does not make a big difference in drag, but it can make driving fast [lethal](https://www.motor1.com/news/130143/worst-sports-cars-audi-tt/). From the linked article:

> Shortly after it was launched in the end of 1998, the TT received a lot of attention from the press. But it was for no good reason – a series of high-speed accidents with fatalities were reported. Many of them occurred during lane changes at speeds in excess of 110 miles per hour (180 kilometers per hour), or in sharp turns.

Comment: So answer at my question is round edges dont have any advantages,they only  introduce handling problems and Porsche use it  just for stayling reason. Job done

Comment: @LostincurvedSpace-Time Did it really need multiple questions on several communities for that? And Porsche can only afford the rounded edges because they have a spoiler **upstream** of them.

Comment: in neither of your answers you didnt talk about round edge adventages ,so I put new specific question only about that...

Comment: @LostincurvedSpace-Time Why should I write about advantages when there aren't any?

Comment: Because I dont know that.If you wrote this,I wouldn't ask new question.

Answer (score 4):

The idea of a round and tapered rear end on a car is to delay *flow separation* at the backside of the car, which adds to drag. Tapering and lengthening the car adds to its *wetted area*, which also adds drag. At some point, adding length to the taper adds more drag by wetted area then is subtracted by flow separation delay, and at that point the car designer just truncates the taper, declares the job done, and goes home early to read magazines for the rest of the afternoon.

Comment: If round back reduce drag,why all ultra low drag vehicle use cut off,sharp edges tail ?

Comment: my answer explains this. please note that to completely eliminate flow separation drag, the tail has to be too long for practical use on a road vehicle, this is another reason the designers truncate the tail.

Comment: but you can truncate tail in two ways: 1.cut off with sharp edges or 2. cut off with round edges ..and still keep  same length..

Comment: rounding the edges might make a small difference in separation drag reduction, but at that point it's up to the *stylists*. right now, the sharp edges are "cool".

Comment: @LostincurvedSpace-Time So your trunk isn't useless. And sharp edges are fragile.

Comment: @nielsnielsen There is no point in arguing with this person. Referring her/him to the [Kammback](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/668653/why-car-has-sharp-separation-edges-at-the-back/668843?r=SearchResults&s=1|88.6449#668843) development doesn't help, s/he seems to want her/his opinion confirmed even though the evidence points in the other direction.

Comment: @PeterKämpf, thanks for the advice, I suspected this was the case but appreciate your insights. -NN

Comment: @PeterKampf here I find video about Kammtail: https://youtu.be/HSQcVcyogKY